# Is there a way where the user input the data on the app (Android Studio) and it will be display via on Button from the database(Firebase)

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to create an application using android studio. I want the user to input their children names. The children name will be stored and used as a button for each name for the next page/activity.

So far I have managed to store the data. But not displayed it.

Below is my java code:
Update I was able to call out the names. Now I'm having trouble in linking it to the next page.

```
 fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user=fAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user!=null) {
        mUid = user.getUid();
    }

    //btn1
    dbFire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbRef = dbFire.getReference().child("User").child(mUid).child("childName").child("1");

    childBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.child1);

            Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").orderByChild("mUid").equalTo(mUid);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        String ChildName = ""+ds.child("childName").child("1").child("childName").getValue();
                        childBtn1.setText(ChildName);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    childBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "via in Button"?

Comment: Please paste your code here, don't just link it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the activity that You will use to display the data.

Then you need to get the data and list them into variables: read [how to get data from firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Then you need to set the button value getting the child name with a simple foreach into the list of data that you' ve got by firebase

To change the button value you can simply do `buttonName.setText(String);`

Comment: Thank u so much!! Wait I try to do!!

Comment: helppppp..still cant run ;;;. Do i doit wrongly?

Comment: We need your code and the errors